# Android app using Google cloud Endpoints: Datastore vs SQL

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I want to develop a new Android application and I was wondering about the architecture to use.
My idea is to host my app on Google App Engine, using the Google Cloud Endpoints as backend.
The only problem is that Google Cloud Endpoints use Google Datastore (that is a non-relational database, while I wanted to use a relational one).

So my questions are:

-Is there the possibility to change the logic of Google Cloud Endpoints using Google Cloud SQL ?

-If not, is there the possibility to use Google Datastore in a relational way (with references between tables) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there the possibility to change the logic of Google Cloud Endpoints
>   using Google Cloud SQL ?

Google Cloud Endpoints's purpose is to allow you to develop REST apis for your application.
What's inside the implementation of the REST methods is totally your choice. You can call Google Data Store, Google Cloud SQL, call MemCache, call other services, whatever you want. Cloud Endpoints does not force you to use anything. Its main purpose is to handle the communication RESTfully. That's all.

> If not, is there the possibility to use Google Datastore in a
>   relational way (with references between tables) ?

If that's all you want , entity references are managed using `Key`s in Google Data Store. But That does not make it relational. For example it will not complain if you delete an entity referenced by other entities like RDMSs normally do.

Comment: Thank you @M.Sameer; but can you recommend me some guides that show how to use Google Sql with Endpoints? I didn't find nothing about that (Endpoints use Datastore as default setting) .
About the second question, can I use foreign keys between two tables?

Comment: Endpoints does not use anything as default setting.. if you are talking about what the Eclipse plugin generates .. consider it an example and just delete it .. I do that because I use Objectify instead of JPA or JDO and it works fine .. I did not use Cloud SQL but it has nothing to do with Endpoints for sure.

Comment: In Data Store, any Entity must have a unique Key. This key is used to reference this entity in other entities. It's similar to the FK in relational databases but not exactly the same like the example I mentioned in the answer and another example is that you cannot make composite keys. You should read more about the data store and compare it with cloud sql to know what is best for you. Also do not forget to compare their billing policies.

Comment: Perfect; I will try to use Cloud SQL, changing the code generated by the automatic procedure (and not using the key). Thank you @M.Sameer; if I have some problems I will write hear.